# Is kale's Vitamin K content a source of MK4?

Tags: vitamins, fractures

I've seen some studies that indicate MK4, a chemical from certain types of Vitamin K, is capable of preventing and reducing bone fractures.

I believe kale is the food with the most Vitamin K; however, I am unsure whether the vitamin K from it gives MK4 or MK7.

If you have a link, that'd be great.

Comment: We are currently considering removing nutrition from the site scope, see [the discusstion on meta](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/137/reviewing-the-site-scope). I'm closing this as off-topic for the moment. If you'd like to make a case for keeping Nutrition, please take part in the meta discussion

Comment: It doesn't.  It relates to the "Nutrition" part of the "Fitness & Nutrition" in big letters at the top of the page.

Comment: That's why I pointed you to the Meta discussion. I'm trying to make the site more focused on actual Fitness and not allow any question that's related to Nutrition.

Comment: Change the title of the site if you're not going to entertain questions that 50% of the title suggests.

Comment: I don't know why you closed my question because of YOUR stupidity to not change the title of the site.

Comment: From the FAQ, "Topics include exercise and training, nutrition and diets"

Comment: Nick, @Josie we are actually currently in the process of redefining the site scope and hence also the name. If you'd like to get involved in the discussion (make a case for keeping "Nutrition" in, as we are currently going towards kicking it out) you should write an answer to the Meta question Ivo linked to above.

Comment: I'm not really interested in meta discussions.  However, I think you should either allow nutrition questions UNTIL you remove "nutrition" from the title of the site, or go ahead and remove that part of the title quickly.  I'm sure I'm not the only one bothered by the rude comments left on these (i.e. "Care to explain.. ?")

Comment: @Nick, I've updated my comment to be more diplomatic, you'll have to pardon my English if it came over as being rude. We didn't make the title, but we do get to have a say on what Nutrition in the title implies. Btw you are already participating in a 'meta' discussion, simply in the wrong location.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I posted it.  Now we're in a meta meta discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, both MK4 and MK7 are types of Vitamin K2, whereas Kale would only contain K1, being a plant.

As far as sources go, I believe plants contain K1, animal products (meat, eggs, dairy, grass-fed butter!) contain MK4 and bacteria produce MK7, which is therefor found in fermented food (Sauerkraut, Natto! Yoghurt... ).

Comment: I thought the body converted K1 into the MK4 form of K2?  Is this not correct?

Comment: However, supplementation of K1 appears to have no positive effect (unless it fixes a deficiency). The body seems to convert K1 to K2 at a fixed rate, and K1 is inactive in the body. Supplementation of K2 on top of what the body produces is what's beneficial.